# jQuery Mobile populate listview with PHP + AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to populate a listview of jQueryMobile with contents from PHP side.

load_info.php file have the following code:

```
if(isset($_GET['type'])){
    switch($_GET['type']){
        case 'locale': 
            load_locale("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
            break;
    }   
}

function load_locale($host, $user, $pass, $db){
    $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    $db->set_charset("utf8");
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT `desc` FROM locale");
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($desc);
    $query->store_result();
    $rows = array();
    while($query->fetch()){
        $rows[] = array("value" => $desc);
    }

    $query->close();
    $db->close();

    return json_encode($rows);      
}
```

And in the index.php page, I have the following:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-locale"> 
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-close-btn="right">
        <h1>Locale</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="content">  
        <ul id="listview_locale" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-autodividers="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page-locale", function() {
            $(function(){
                var items = "";
                $.getJSON("load_info.php?type=locale",function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(index, item) 
                    {
                        items += "<li>" + item.value + "</li>";
                    });
                    $("#listview_locale").html(items); 
                    $("#listview_locale").trigger("change");
                    $("#listview_locale").trigger("refresh");
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Although, when I click the button to go to the page id #page-locale, the listview has nothing. I don't receive any error, but also it has no content.

What is wrong?

**Edit: Solved.** 
Instead of

```
$.getJSON("load_info.php?type=locale", function(data){
```

must be

```
$.getJSON("classes/load_info.php?type=locale", function(data){
```

instead of

```
load_locale("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
```

must be

```
echo load_locale("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

your array is multi-dimension array so u have to convert the inner array too

```
  while($query->fetch()){
        $data = array("value" => $desc)   
        $rows[] = json_encode($data);
    }
```

**EDIT**

If u declare like this

```
echo load_locale("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
```

add `exit;`

code should be:

```
echo load_locale("localhost", "root", "", "testing"); 
exit;
```

if you give `break`..it will break the switch statement not stop the whole process

you can declare like this too

```
if(isset($_GET['type'])){
    switch($_GET['type']){
        case 'locale': 
            echo load_locale("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
            break;
    }  
    exit; 
}
```